# Find which process is being joined by another?

Tags: process

If I have opened Nautilus and spawned a new Nautilus instance, a new PID is created for the new Nautilus instance. Shortly after, the instance is joined with the main Nautilus program running.

Main nautilus instance:

```
manos@box:~$ ps aux | grep nautilus
manos     2687  1.1  2.0 1190968 77580 ?       Sl   11:40   0:24 /usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service
```

Spawning a new instance:

```
manos@box:~$ nautilus&
[1] 15447
```

Shortly, PID 15447 disappears as it joins 2687. Is there a way to follow this? Namely is there a general way to see that 15447 "becomes" 2687?

Comment: `nautilus` uses `--gapplication-service` (as you can see from that output). _In GApplication it's possible that the instance of the application that is started from the command line is not the instance that will ultimately respond to the request. This is due to application uniqueness: if the application is already running, the request must be forwarded. In the case that the application has been split into a launcher and service then this forwarding happens every time._ See also [Description](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gio/GApplication.html) on FDO page.